# Why does my strlen seem to be returning two values within this for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, strlen

Basically I am trying to create the d&d dice roller using my (basic) knowledge of C. In the `for`-loop which is supposed to cycle through the input and return the number of sides in the dice, `strlen()` seems to return two seperate values: 1. the correct value, 2. an extremely large number. I cannot figure out why it is returning the second number and this messes up the `for`-loop.

I have tried assigning `strlen()` to another variable called length and calling on that in the function where I use `strlen()`. Everytime I print `strlen()` in the function where the input `dice_inp` exists it prints the correct value, but as soon as I pass it to `sides()` it returns the extremely large number.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <math.h>

int num();
int sides();

int main()
{
    printf("This is a dice rolling simulator for D&D!\n");
    int num_dice, num_sides;
    num_dice = num();
    num_sides = sides();
    printf("num %d sides %d", num_dice, num_sides);
}

int num()
{
    int i, keynum, dice_num = 0, length;
    char dice_inp[20];

    printf("Input the number of dice(n), then d,then the number of sides of each dice(s) so the input appears n the form 'nds'!\n");
    scanf("%s", dice_inp);
    length = abs(strlen(dice_inp));

    keynum = strcspn(dice_inp, "d");

    for (i = 0; i < keynum; i++)
    {
        char c = dice_inp[keynum - 1 - i];
        c = c - '0';
        c = round(c*pow(10, i));
        dice_num += c;
    }

    if (dice_num == 1)
    {
        printf("There is %d dice being rolled.\n", dice_num);
        Sleep(500);
    }

    else if (dice_num == 0)
    {
        printf("You cannot roll 0 dice.\n");
        Sleep(500);
        num();
    }

    else if (dice_num > 1)
    {
        printf("There are %d dice being rolled.\n", dice_num);
        Sleep(500);
    }

    Sleep(500);
    sides(length, dice_inp, keynum);
    return dice_num;
}

int sides(int length, char dice_inp[], int keynum)
{
    int i, dice_sides = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < abs((length - keynum - 1)); i++)
    {
        char c = dice_inp[strlen(dice_inp) - 1 - i];
        c = c - '0';
        c = round(c*pow(10, i));
        dice_sides += c;
        printf("a");
    }

    if (dice_sides == 1)
    {
        printf("A dice cannot have one side. Please try again!\n");
        Sleep(500);
        num();
    }

    else if (dice_sides == 0)
    {
        printf("A dice cannot have 0 sides. Please try again.\n");
        Sleep(500);
        num();
    }
    else if (dice_sides > 1)
    {
        printf("The dice will have %d sides.\n", dice_sides);
        Sleep(500);
    }

    printf("%d", dice_sides);
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `abs` in `abs(strlen(dice_inp));`?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what's a "d&d dice roller"? Please note that a function that takes no arguments in C should have a parameter list that is `void`. ... *`int num()`* *~>* `int num(void)` and so on.

Comment: ^^^ more precisely, [`strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) is specified to return [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t), so `abs` is pointless. And `c = round(c*pow(10, i));` has a particular code smell, as it converts a double to `char`. Finally, what `int` value did you intend `sides` to actually return, because it claims it does, but not a single `return` within can be found.

Comment: @Swordfish Dungeons and Dragons uses dice with differing numbers of sides, not only traditional 6-sided dice.

Comment: @Swordfish [in case you've never seen them before](https://www.dieharddice.com/what-are-dnd-dice).

Comment: @Swordfish The notation is something like 3d12 to mean roll 3 dice with 12 sides each.

Comment: *Dungeons and Dragons uses dice with differing numbers of sides* – O.O Sorcery!

Comment: Why don't you just use `scanf("%dd%d", &dice_num, &sides)`?

Comment: Are you sure that your problem originates from the `sides(length, dice_inp, keynum)` call within function `num` and not from the `num_sides = sides()` call within function `main`?

Comment: When you call `sides()` from inside `num()` you don't use the result. Then in `main()` you call it with no arguments, which causes undefined behavior.

Comment: Please read the following blogpost: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). It may help you resolving similar problems yourself in the future

Comment: @WhozCraig It's not that I've never played in a dungeon before. That's never been with dice, though.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of problems in your code.
First of all, the function "sides" is defined in the following way:

```
int sides(int length, char dice_inp[], int keynum);
```

but you call it without parameters

```
num_sides = sides();
```

When you got an invalid input, in the function "num", you call it again recursively, this lead to a waste of stack. It's better to use a loop. In the same function, when you call it recursively, you lost the return value. This means that at the end you get the wrong value. The function "Sleep" inside that function are meaningless for me.

I'm guessing that the problem with strlen is related to the fact that the input string doesn't contains the terminator. Try to use printf to trace the input before the strlen.

The problems I described here are not the only ones.